# Diferença entre utilizar o elemento main versus um div com role="main"?

Tags: html, html5

Pensando em termos de acessibilidade, descritos pelo [WAI-ARIA](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/aria), é preciso definir o elemento com o conteúdo principal da página com `role="main"`, de modo a melhorar a acessibilidade da página para usuários que contam com tecnologias assistivas.

Por exemplo:

```
<html>
...
<body>
    ...
    <div role="main">
        Conteúdo principal da página
    </div>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

Contudo, o HTML5 já define um elemento `main`.

Minha dúvida é, se eu substituir o código acima por esse código abaixo, as ferramentas assistivas conseguirão prover a mesma funcionalidade? Semanticamente, `<div role="main">` é igual a `<main>`? Ou seja, o `<main>` tem um `role="main"` implícito?

```
<html>
...
<body>
    ...
    <main>
        Conteúdo principal da página
    </main>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O elemento `main` possui a semântica `role="main"` implicitamente por padrão.

[Referência](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#wai-aria) <sup>(em inglês)</sup>:

```
Language feature  |  Default implicit ARIA semantic  |  Restrictions
____________________________________________________________________________________
main element      |  main role                       | Role must be either document,
                  |                                  | application, or main
```

---

`<main>`, `<div role="main">` e `<main role="main">`¹ possuem o mesmo valor de semântica ARIA, pois todos eles indicam (implícita ou explicitamente) seu `role` como `main`.

¹ O exemplo `<main role="main">` possui um valor `role` explícito que sobrescreve o valor de `role` implícito do elemento, mas como o valor atribuído explicitamente é o mesmo que o valor padrão implícito, o `role="main"` torna-se redundante neste caso.

Note que minha resposta até o presente momento se refere apenas a browsers e leitores de tela atualizados. Existem programas mais antigos que suportam `role="main"` mas não suportam o elemento `main` que é uma adição relativamente recente do HTML5, então `<main role="main">` pode ser útil visando a compatibilidade com programas desatualizados. ([referência](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18664038/1331430) <sup>(em inglês)</sup>).